# Return column for selected row python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet that I am managing using OpenPyXL and it looks like this:

[image]

Basically, the program should print the whole column for the selected column from the first row.

```
selectCol = input("Select col: ")
# lets say selectCol = 'Model'
# program will output: a, b, c

# lets say selectCol = 'Item'
# program will output: test, test2, test3
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the Excel file is loaded in a dataframe (df) and selectCol has been 'inputed', simply try:

```py
df.loc[:, selectCol]
```